# Display one version of image at multiple places in Magento?

Tags: templates, magento

If you go [this page](http://www.princessly.com/graceful-ball-gown-strapless-sweetheart-drop-waist-tiered-chapel-wedding-dress.html), you'll notice I'm displaying the same version of image at 2 different places: one for the cloud zoom, and one at the middle of the page without zooming.

I'm currently using 2 different lines of code to generate the image and then return the URL of it, which essentially does the same thing:

```
<?php /* for cloud zoom */ echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->setWatermarkImageOpacity(0)->resize(600, null);?>

<?php /* for middle page */ echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->setWatermarkImageOpacity(0)->resize(600, null);?>
```

This is undoubtedly a lame solution because: 1) it occupies more disk storage as there are 2 distinct image files which are essentially the same image; 2) it significantly slows the page load as the user has to download both images.

So my question is how can I use the same version of image at multiple places in Magento? Is there any way to get the resize() method to return the URL of the image?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image` has a `__toString()` method that does exactly that:

```
$imageUrl = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->__toString();
```

HTH